# What is the use and the difference between textOffsetToCursorPosition cursorPositionToTextOffset in the code snippet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the use and the difference between textOffsetToCursorPosition cursorPositionToTextOffset in the code snippet?

```
// Note:
// - What's called "cursor position" is expressed as { row: x, column: y } and is how Ace Editor get/set the cursor position
// - A "range" defines a selection with a start and end cusor position, expressed as { start: <CursorPos>, end: <CursorPos> }
// - A "text offset" below is the absolute position of the cursor in the string, as would be used in the indexOf() function.
rangeToTextOffsets(range, body) {
    //  BODY is this.state.note.body
    return {
        start: this.cursorPositionToTextOffset(range.start, body),
        end: this.cursorPositionToTextOffset(range.end, body),
    };
}
currentTextOffset() {
    return this.cursorPositionToTextOffset(this.editor_.editor.getCursorPosition(), this.state.note.body);
    // range.end = this.editor_.editor.getCursorPosition() where getCursorPosition is an ace editor function
    // getCursorPosition => row and columns
}
cursorPositionToTextOffset(cursorPos, body) {
    // this is checking for all cases basically asking for do we have stuff caszz
    if (!this.editor_ || !this.editor_.editor || !this.state.note || !this.state.note.body) return 0;
    const noteLines = body.split('\n');
    console.log(`noteLies ${noteLines}`);
    // Javascipt function will split on the occurance of a newline
    // body is this.state.note.body but okay i see ya
    // we split nodes into different array elements
    let pos = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < noteLines.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) pos++; // Need to add the newline that's been removed in the split() call above
        if (i === cursorPos.row) {
            pos += cursorPos.column;
            break;
        } else {
            pos += noteLines[i].length;
        }
    }
    return pos; // returning column? only?
}
textOffsetToCursorPosition(offset, body) {
    const lines = body.split('\n');
    let row = 0;
    let currentOffset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const line = lines[i];
        if (currentOffset + line.length >= offset) {
            console.log('textOffsetToCursorPosition')
            console.log(row + ' ' + currentOffset);
            return {
                row: row,
                column: offset - currentOffset,
            };
        }
        row++;
        currentOffset += line.length + 1;
        console.log(row);
        console.log(currentOffset);
    }
}
```

here is the link to the complete file [Joplin/github](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin/blob/master/ElectronClient/gui/NoteText.jsx)

Comment: Like the comment at the top says, **cursor position** is represented by two numbers (`row` and `column`) and **text offset** by only one number (number of characters from the start till the cursor position).

Comment: No, cursor position will be `{row: 1, column: 11}` (because `s` is on the second line and it is the 11th character (including white spaces)) and offset will be `16` because of spaces and the new line character.

Comment: You've edited the comment, the indexes that I've mentioned in my previous commend are valid for `Hey <br/> my name is Rishabh`.

Comment: thanks for the help, I'm just getting to know how to use StackOverflow, (i did not know that you cannot add linebreaks in comment), but I've my doubt clear :D